# Plot geom_col and geom_line with different x-axis percentage scales on the same graph in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following example data:

```
df <- data.frame(list(Category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
        "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D","E", 
        "E", "E"), Axis2 = c(0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
        0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.53, 0.53, 0.53, 0.67, 0.67, 0.67, 0.42, 
        0.42, 0.42), Offices = c("Office 1", "Office 2", "Office 3", 
        "Office 1", "Office 2", "Office 3", "Office 1", "Office 2", 
        "Office 3", "Office 1", "Office 2", "Office 3", "Office 1", 
        "Office 2", "Office 3", "Office 1", "Office 2", "Office 3"), 
        Axis1 = c(0.03, 0.02, 0.04, 0.1, 0.08, 0.07, 0.12, 0.211, 
        0.18, 0.05, 0.07, 0.08, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.07, 0.011, 0.012)))
```

I want to plot the `Category` column on the y-axis, the `Axis1` column as the x-axis for the bar plot and the `Axis2` columns as the x-axis for the line plot. The fill of the bar plot is also determined by the `Category` column. The data is then faceted by `Offices`.

I have the following code for the plot:

```
ggplot(df) + theme_minimal() + guides(fill = FALSE) +
  geom_col(aes(x = Axis1, y = Category, fill = Category)) +  
  geom_line(aes(x = Axis2, y = Category), stat = "identity", group = 1) +
  labs(y = element_blank(), x = "Percentage of Thing 1") +
  facet_wrap(~Offices, ncol = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./max(data$Compliance), 
                                         label=scales::percent)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, color = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 18, color = "black", 
        face = "bold", margin = margin(c(0.2,0,0.6,0), unit = "in")),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, color = "black", 
        margin = margin(c(0.2,0,0.1,0), unit = "in")),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "gray86"),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

I am facing 3 main issues:

1. The location of the second x-axis, I want it to be under the facet titles right above the plot.
2. The second x-axis labels are not showing the data in `Axis2` column
3. Both plots seem to still be using the main x-axis scale because the bar plots are shrunken to accommodate the line plot. I want them to be independent of each other where the y axis is shared but the x-axes are not.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place the strip labels above the axis use `strip.placement= "outside"`. To get the right scales for your axes you also have to scale the data to be plotted on the secondary scale.

```r
library(ggplot2)

scale <- max(df$Axis1)

ggplot(df) +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  geom_col(aes(x = Axis1, y = Category, fill = Category)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Axis2 * scale, y = Category), stat = "identity", group = 1) +
  labs(y = element_blank(), x = "Percentage of Thing 1") +
  facet_wrap(~Offices, ncol = 3) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / scale, label = scales::percent)
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11, color = "black"),
    strip.text = element_text(
      size = 18, color = "black",
      face = "bold", margin = margin(c(0.2, 0, 0.6, 0), unit = "in")
    ),
    axis.title.x = element_text(
      size = 12, color = "black",
      margin = margin(c(0.2, 0, 0.1, 0), unit = "in")
    ),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "gray86"),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Stephan everything worked great, my only problem is if I add a title to the seconday axis it still remains outside/above of the strip facet title `sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / scale, name = "Percentage of Thing2", label=scales::percent)`

Comment: Hi Maral. Yeah. I see. I don't know of any theme options to place the axis title between the strip text and the axis text. But a hack would be to "move" the secondary axis title via `theme(..., axis.title.x.top = element_text(vjust = -25))`. At least for your example plot that seemed to work.